# Querydsl produces UnsupportedOperationException after spring boot upgrade from 2.1 to 2.3

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, querydsl

My project was using querydsl 4.1.3 and spring-boot 2.1.x
After upgrading to querydsl 4.4 and spring-boot 2.3.x i'm having this error:

```
2020-11-19 18:24:22.683 ERROR 26060 --- [  XNIO-1 task-2] io.undertow.request                      : UT005023: Exception handling request to /eaud/login

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap.put(Collections.java:1457)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visitConstant(JPQLSerializer.java:327)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:221)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:36)
    at com.querydsl.core.types.ConstantImpl.accept(ConstantImpl.java:140)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:122)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visitOperation(SerializerBase.java:301)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.visitOperation(JPQLSerializer.java:437)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:262)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.visit(SerializerBase.java:36)
    at com.querydsl.core.types.OperationImpl.accept(OperationImpl.java:83)
    at com.querydsl.core.support.SerializerBase.handle(SerializerBase.java:122)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPQLSerializer.serialize(JPQLSerializer.java:220)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPAQueryBase.serialize(JPAQueryBase.java:60)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.JPAQueryBase.serialize(JPAQueryBase.java:50)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.createQuery(AbstractJPAQuery.java:98)
    at com.querydsl.jpa.impl.AbstractJPAQuery.fetchOne(AbstractJPAQuery.java:252)
    at br.gov.cgu.eaud.negocio.auth.UsuarioRepository.getPorCpfSeExistir(UsuarioRepository.java:63)
```

The query that produces the error is a very simple one:

```java
  private QUsuario usuario = QUsuario.usuario;

  public Usuario getPorCpfSeExistir(String cpf) {
        return getJPAQuery()
                .select(this.usuario)
                .from(this.usuario)
                .where(this.usuario.cpf.eq(cpf))
                .fetchOne();
    }
```

The method getJPAQuery is a simple `return new JPAQueryFactory(this.getEntityManager());`

I've tried using the version that comes with spring-boot 2.3, i.e, querydsl:4.3.1, but it won't work either. The version 4.1.3 also doesn't work.

Any clues on what could be causing this?

Comment: I think you have a mismatching version between querydsl-core and querydsl-jpa. Did you bump both to 4.4.0?

Comment: @Jan-WillemGmeligMeyling yes.. =/

Comment: Could you verify by running `SerializerBase.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` and `JPQLSerializer.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`? This is really an issue we frequently see with users that don't bump both dependencies (or have one dependency replaced with a lower version one due to a transitive dependency). Also, you could verify the used version with `mvn dependency:tree`.

Comment: OK, solved it after cleaning caches of my maven... Look's like it wasn't updating acording to my POM. Thank you!

Comment: glad it works now!

Answer (score 0):

OK, solved it after cleaning caches of my maven... Look's like it wasn't updating my project acording to my POM.